# How small does a land-mass have to be before you live "on" it, rather than "in" it?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I'm sure virtually everyone agrees that people live **on** the Isle of Wight, but **in** Ireland.

Apparently the usage depends somewhat on physical size, but that can't be the whole story. How exactly do we decide which form to use? And are there any really glaring 'outliers' that don't fit the normal pattern?

LATER - I must just add that the most uncertain case I've found so far is **The Falklands**. Most people go for **in** there, but a substantial minority (about 1 in 3) opt for **on**.

Comment: Is the Isle of Wight larger than Ireland?

Comment: Ireland:70,286 km2. Isle of Wight:380 km2. Antarctica:14,000,000 km2.

Comment: Isn't there a semantic difference between the sentences? You live _on_ a land mass but you live _in_ a nation/city/place. So you could rearrange that to be "I live on the isle of Ireland". So I'm not sure size is relevant. The isles of wight/mann/scilly are the names of the islands themselves, not of the countries they represent. Edit: whoops, Neil Fein got an answer in first.

Comment: The answer you are looking for is 42 acres.

Comment: @billynomates: First define your terms. Douglas Adams only gave us the *number*, not the *units*. Maybe it's 42 square kilometers, or square miles.

Comment: @FumbleFingers He meant 42 acres. He told me personally. We were bros.

Comment: When I read the question on the hot list, thought it was about **physics**!

Comment: @Cawas: Apparently we're a broad church here at EL&U. Quite apart from exploring the geographical and political aspects of the question, we've got references to **astrophysics** here. Only interplanetary thus far, but perhaps someone will reach out to interstellar regions soon. How about it, Trekkies?

Comment: I think one would live in Australia but on New Zealand. :)

Comment: @Marcus Lindblom: Actually it was pointed out to me earlier that one lives **in** New Zealand, but **on** North or South Island.

Comment: I live on Earth.

Comment: And what about "at"? I live on/in Ireland, in/on Earth, in Dublin, on/in/at McPaddy Street. This is all very confusing.

Comment: @billynomates: Let's not get carried away! The Welsh in particular are prone to say they live "**by** 'ere**". Prepositionally speaking, it seems one can live almost anywhere.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You mean live anypreposition a place.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: I was being **tichy** (tongue-in-cheek), but 5 gets you 10 someone will come up with another preposition that can be used in this way.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I love saying "by yerr" whilst in England. It confuses the hell out of people.

Comment: I live off the land. Also consider "I live overseas", "I live above ground", "I live for Israel", ...

Comment: I don't see where Jon agreed to any bet.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "you can see why now" -- Yeah, I guess I was a stupid ignoramus before (my own posts). "a nit-picker might disqualify it" -- anyone who didn't want to give you their money for no good reason would disqualify "live off the land", if they had been silly enough to take your bet. But there was no bet, there was just you talking to yourself.

Comment: *I'm sure virtually everyone agrees that people live on the Isle of Wight* - if you can call that living.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Hmm. There are people *on* Mount Everest. Maybe it's not size, but ratio of width to height? Planets, islands, and mountains have a low ratio, but countries and cities have a high one.

Comment: @Tom Anderson: Nah. I think Neil pretty much nailed this one. The dominant factor is whether or not the area is primarily recognised as a social/political/cultural entity, or a geographical one. But as ever, there are exceptions. And "fuzzy" ones, of which **The Falklands** is definitely my favourite, as a Brit.

Comment: I would guess that the difference between 3-D and 2-D might have something to do with it, too. Fillmore goes into this in the [first](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/MayWeComeIn.pdf) [two](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Space.pdf) chapters of his 1971 Santa Cruz [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/FillmoreDeixisLectures.pdf).

Comment: @John Lawler: I haven't yet followed up all your background links about this 2D/3D stuff yet, but I'm supposing it's a bit more complex than just plane geometry. When I first asked the question I really did think "size matters" - but Neil straightened me out on that one as deftly as a sex therapist!

Comment: The first two chapters (intro and Space) go into dimensionality and prepositions. Very nice examples.

Comment: @John Lawler: haha - Filmore put me straight into "broad-based interpretation" mode there! So on his *May we come in?* (partly biased by his mention that C might be a pet beaver) I couldn't read the rest without constantly thinking it might have been said by trail-dusty cowboys asking the Madame of the town bordello whether they could dispense with the "withdrawal method" of contraception! Interested to see mention of Robin Lakoff, on account of a latter-day namesake in my answer [to this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24655) back when I first started posting here.

Comment: George and Robin were my thesis advisors, back in 1973. We would pretty much agree on most things, though not on everything. I was at Santa Cruz when the lectures were given, and it was all new stuff to me then. That was the first mention I can remember of the term _deixis_.

Comment: @John Lawler: I didn't move in such rarefied circles (just a one-year module in linguistics in '71), but I remember having my eyes opened by our lecturer showing us how little information is contained in the actual *words* of a typical statement, compared to how much we have to "back-fill" using our knowledge of the universe in general, and the local context in particular. I hadn't even seen a computer at that time, but it seems to me I've spent the 40-odd years since then explaining to people that computers aren't going to be understanding natural language any time soon.

Comment: You might enjoy [our book](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/routledge/BOOK.ZIP), then. It's 13 years old, but it forecast the future pretty well, at least in the [last 2 chapters](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/routledge/book-7.pdf).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2251/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-john-lawler)

Comment: The Man in the Moon is an awkward customer.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In my experience, this is often based on whether one is speaking of geographical versus political locations, and also the context of what you're saying. You would be "on" an island or continent or planet, but you'd be "in" a country or city or region.

So:

- One would live **in** England, China, Canada, New York City, North America. (Political locales.)
- One *might* be located **on** the British isles, Manhattan Island, **on** ***the continent of*** North America, the planet Mars. (Geographical locations.)

It's kind of fuzzy, though, because I've heard of people living in Africa or Antarctica. Can anyone think of exceptions to this—this is English, of course there will be some—or help clarify further?

---

Edit: Wow, that's quite the discussion going on in the comments!

I'm convinced that while this answer is an extreme generalization, it does seems to serve as a good starting point, if nothing else. Like everything else in English, there are no absolutes.

- There's some consensus that multiple islands (Hawaii, Japan) forces a political interpretation, and you'd live **in** Japan but **on** ***the island of*** Honshu (although you'd live *in* Honshu).
- There's also some disagreement about whether you live **on** or **in** a continent.

Comment: We also live in a world, but on a planet, on the Earth even.

Comment: @Sam - Speak for yourself, Earthling. :)

Comment: Antarctica may be a pivotal case. I know people don't really live there permanently, but while they *are* there, I suspect they usually live *on* it. Even though it's much bigger than, say, Vatican City.

Comment: Not sure about this, but maybe it has something to do with man-made borders? As in, countries and cities have borders, you live *in* the borders. But continents and islands have coastlines, even though the landmass keeps going until the sea floor.

Comment: Do I live on the British Isles or in them? I would say in.

Comment: +1 It's not a question of size but of context. Most New Yorkers live *in* Manhattan, but *on* Long Island. (Well, most New Yorkers actually live in Brooklyn or Queens). However, if for some reason they did say Manhattan Island, they would indeed say *on* it. Similarly, people would live *on* the island of Great Britain, even though they live *in* Great Britain.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - I would say one lives *on* the British Isles, but *in* Great Britan.

Comment: Indeed, I think *multiple* islands forces a political interpretation (e.g. you can't live "on" Hawaii, you can only live on Maui, the Big Island, etc). Living "on" a continent doesn't work for me either - you live "in" Africa, Australia, Antarctica, North America, South America, Eurasia.

Comment: I like the core insight of politics vs geography, but I think the relationship needs to be refined a bit. When the two align (e.g. Australia, Tasmania, arguably Antarctica depending on how someone views it), the political interpretation wins (i.e. use "in"). Similarly, politics wins when the political entity spans multiples islands, or when the regional name has a land border (including the Africa/Eurasia border and the North/South America border at the Suez and Panama canals).

Comment: Only for purely geographical descriptions does "on" make sense: "on the Australian mainland", "on the same island as London". However, at the planetary level, I think @Alain's answer kicks in and those will always be "on" (due to the whole surface-of-a-sphere aspect). People may someday live "in" Ceres and other asteroids though (albeit in a quite literal sense).

Comment: Also, a 'near neighbour' to someone living *on* any island may be said to live *on the mainland*. But of course that mainlander might live *on the moor*, *in the valley*, or *up the mountain*. And within that, they might live *up* or *down* the road, or *on* some particular named road.

Comment: Anecdotally, "on" Greenland sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @mskfisher: Me too. The point is that *some* people (maybe 10% if I'm to believe Google more than it merits) go for **in** with Greenland, which at least makes it something of a borderline case. Notwithstanding @Neil Fein's earlier comment, I don't think there's anything like even that level of support for people living **on** the British Isles.

Comment: I live on the continent of North America, while I reside in America, not on America. The continent, or physical ground, is what I live on. The country, or political entity, is what I live in.

Comment: I really think this is the rule, not sure there are exceptions though. Faroe Islands or Sri Lanka hit my mind first, but it turns out, that people live **in** Faroe Islands/Sri Lanka.

Comment: @EveryoneAbove: OK, I'm sold on the politics vs geography (+culture?) angle. Not least because it lets me link the uncertain political status of **The Falklands** with significant ambivalence about which preposition to use in that particular case.

Comment: I think the political vs geographical 'rule' is over general. I suspect that you always live 'in' a political area, but can live both 'in' and 'on' a geographical one. I live in Tasmania, which is geographical. I live in the state of Tasmania, which is political. I live in Australia. No one lives on Australia, nor on Tasmania.

Comment: @Richard A: I'm not buying into *any* absolute rules. There are several 'tendencies', including use of **in** for social / political / cultural locations and those which plural names, **on** for anything called *Island* or *Isle*, etc. No rule has absolute priority, and there's not total agreement on correct usage for some locations. But I'm reasonably satisfied with this particular answer (apart from @Neil Fein's somewhat odd assertion that I might live **on** the British Isles).

Comment: Having said that, although it sound totally unacceptable for *me* to live **on** the British Isles, I'd be less bothered by that usage when refering to, say, *plants that grow on the British Isles*. I still don't really like it though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - That's how we say it here in New Joisey. You live **in** Britan, **in** England, but **on** those British Isles. Gonna go have me a hoagie at the shore now.

Comment: @Neil Fein: I may have missed something, but I can't see anyone saying you can live **on** [some continent]. *On the continent of Africa*, sure, but for all named continents it's **in**. Your answer implies there's some disagreement/discussion on that one, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 5):

I live in Manhattan. I also live on Long Island. Bear in mind that Manhattan is much smaller than Long Island.

Comment: According to Neil, that's because Manhattan is a political entity. BUT: People live *in* Manhattan, and *on* Staten Island. Both of them are islands, and both of them are the same kind of political entity (borough of New York City). So there's not really any logic to this.

Comment: @Mike Baranczak: I think the (imperfectly applied) logic is that you normally live **on** anything with *Island* or *Isle* in its name, and that takes precedence over another rule saying you normally live **in** any placename generally recognised as being a political / administrative entity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: No, people definitely live *in* Rhode Island.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I'm not saying they don't. I was simply explaining to Mike that there are a couple of general rules with reasonably consistent priority. But that doesn't preclude the odd exception proving the rule. Besides, as **The Falklands** clearly shows, there will always be some cases where both usages coexist, and it's pointless trying to identify the 'correct' one.

Comment: @kosmonaut Rhode Island isn't an Island!

Comment: @Joel Spolsky: "Rhode Island" was a counterexample for the assertion that you "live **on** anything with Island or Isle in its name".  Clearly more goes into it than just the name.

Answer (score 2):

Would you live *on* the Napa River Valley or *in* it? I think it may be more related to the containment of the item/object in question. For example, I can stand *on* the ground, *atop* a rock, but *in* a hole, river, or valley. Similarly, fish live *in* the ocean, but ships float *on* it.

In this case it might be more appropriate to think of *in* as *within*. I'm not going *in* the door, I'm standing *within* the walls of the house. The shortened version of that being, "I'm standing in the house."

The same could apply to continents and why the accepted answer notes that some may make reference to "living *in* Africa." This is because they are *within* the borders of the continent of Africa.

Comment: You live *in the Napa River Valley*.  However, if you are right next to the water (or have a houseboat), you could say you live *on the Napa River*.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on the physical geography. You live in the Dales (valleys) but on the Moors.

Comment: As I pointed out (along with various other prepositions) in about the 12th comment against @Robusto's earlier Answer.

Answer (score 1):

You live "on" a hump, but "in" a bowl.  Once something is big enough that it becomes larger or more irregular (no longer expressible as a single characteristic) than a bowl, you change from "in" to "on."

Therefore, "in" Africa or other continent.  "In" Ireland.  When you express the concept of a country as an island, you emphasize it standing out of the water and it becomes a hump, and you change to "on."

This can apply in the plural, so The Falklands can be either multiple bumps, or one political entity.

I believe this generalizes all the other comments made, even the one about Earth - a bump in space.

Listen to the sound of "on the British Isles" and "in the British Isles" and you will be able to discern the isles rising out of the sea in the first case, and being an indistinguishable entity in the second.

Comment: I'm still not sold on the "size" mattering here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's not merely the size that matters, but also the shape.  For example, the word *on* seems to flow rather naturally when talking about with peninsulas; I know people from Massachusetts rarely use the preposition *in*, instead opting for *on*:

> - He was born on Cape Cod, then moved away when he was in his twenties.
> - We'll be vacationing on the Cape next summer.
> - George was born in Cape Town, but now he lives on Cape Cod.
> - Well, my goodness. How often do you see a [bear](http://www.usatoday.com/news/nation/story/2012-06-07/cape-cod-bear/55450090/1) on Cape Cod?

I don't know if there's a hard and fast rule that will always work.  Sometimes local culture might favor one preposition over the other.

Comment: I think it's clear from other answers/comments that there's no "hard and fast rule" in play. Google Books, for example, reports about 2M results for both ***in*** and ***on** the Falkland Islands*, so even the presence of the word "islands" doesn't force the same preposition from everyone. In the end I think the dominant factor is geographical **on** versus political **in**, but even that's only a tendency, not a rule.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree; the only rule is, "There is no one rule," and that was already pretty well-established. (I merely noticed nothing had been said about peninsulas yet, and thought it might be worth adding the note.)

Comment: Yeah - I think I already knew there wouldn't be an absolute rule when I first posed the question. But I did feel a bit sheepish when I realised my original assumption counted for nothing (size loses out to administrative allegiance as well as to performance! :) The note is noted, but I can't in all conscience upvote it!

Comment: Fine by me if you don't want to upvote it ~ I sure wouldn't want you to violate your conscience! :^) It just felt good to get it off my chest. Sometimes the contribution is reward enough, all by itself.

Comment: It *is* a good point, and well made. If it had been a comment, I'm sure I'd have upvoted it straight off. The bar's higher for answers though. Neil's answer went through a fair amount of discussion & revision before I upvoted it, and it wasn't until quite a bit later that I finally "accepted" it (so maybe I'll surprise you with an unexpected upvote many weeks from now! :)