# What is the expression for coughing at the beginning of an utterance officially called?

Tags: onomatopoeia

I was wondering what is the name for the introductory "coughing" in English, i.e. when somebody clears their throat to start their utterance. For example:

> "Ekhm... Welcome! How can I help you?"

Is "ekhm" the right way to spell such onomatopoeia? Are there any other ways to spell it?

Comment: These posts about the [use of fillers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13300/is-it-bad-behavior-to-add-filler-word-such-as-so-um-in-business-speaking) and [hedges](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24655/is-this-usage-of-lol-considered-a-hedge) may be of interest to you.

Comment: What is it called, how do you write it, or what is it? It is called a 'clearing of the throat'. It is written 'ahem'. It is an unvoiced (glottal or laryngeal) nasal. Oh..and it acts as an attention getter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In English, we would most commonly spell this utterance "[Ahem](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ahem)."  It is used to somewhat politely gain someone's attention.

It can be considered a hedge or filler, that is, a vocal delay that allows the speaker time to collect their thoughts while speaking.

I understood what you meant by "ekhm," but I have never seen it spelled that way. However, I imagine that the spelling of a word like this could be subject to regional differences.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just write:

> Cough cough...

But, if you want the "e" version, it's actually:

> Ahem! (not "e")

Comment: Thank you very much, it was on the tip of my tongue, but I simply forgot the spelling. I was looking for "Ahem".