# Why "live on campus" but not "live in campus"

Tags: prepositions, in-on

Why do we say *he lives on campus* but not *he lives in campus*? Technically we live *in* the boundaries of the campus.

Comment: Noah, maybe you should add your example as an answer to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24413)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You live **on** a piece of land which includes several buildings. The same preposition, **on**, is used with the word *farm* as well, and the logic behind it is the same.

Comment: Does a farm have multiple buildings?

Comment: @Noah: To my (extremely) limited experience, apart from the house where the farmer usually lives, there are also barns for the animals.

Comment: I wouldn't try to find logic in it: if you try to apply logic to linguistic questions you often get the wrong answer. The actual answer is "because that's what we do". Americans tend to live _on_ a street; the British used to live _in_ a street, though nowadays they sometimes live _on_ one.

Comment: "Does a farm have multiple buildings?"  Yes, of course.  What an odd question - have you ever seen a farm with strictly one stucture??